# Social Media icons SlideIn with Font Awesome

Tags: html, css

Reference : http://www.techandall.com/demos/socialmediaicons/

I am trying to achieve the same effect of social icons but with Font Awesome, instead of using images.. but I am not sure how can I achieve this without adding extra HTML code, I am trying to use it like this - content:'ssss'; instead of images as in the background..

something like this

```
 .social-icons li.twitter a {
   content:'aaa';
   font-size:10px;
   padding-left:5px;
   color:#000;
 }
```

In the code above I have intentionally removed "font-family as font-awesome for testing.. can I do it like this OR I will have to modify the HTML and add extra span to slideIn and slideOut ? here is the Fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/Zkf7A/

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `content` property only works with the :before and :after pseudo-elements.

try changing your styles to

```
.social-icons li.twitter a:before {
    content 'aaa';
    /* etc... */
}
```

you'll probably need to remove `text-indent` from `a` and replace with `overflow: hidden;` and set a `width` and `height` to `40px` in your demo, this depends largely on what technique you want to use to hide the original text.

hover `color`

```
.social-icons li.twitter a:hover:before {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can here is an example after you get the font awesome library:

```
.social-icons li.twitter a {
content: "\f099";
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
font-size:10px;
padding-left:5px;
color:#000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Riskbreaker, this is what I used, but it simply doesn't load font in it neither does it slide, is simply fades the color to twitter color..

Comment: make sure you are calling the web font from you master file